# pylint parser - standalone alternative to Jenkins violations plugin

Tags: python, jenkins, pylint

Is there a module that I can use to generate web pages showing violations (reported by pylint) the way Jenkins violations plugin shows them?

I already have a server that runs pylint on sources and generates reports. I want to be able to make web-pages out of the report and send links to concerned teams. I do not want to run Jenkins just for this purpose.

Is there anything that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

You can have pylint generate the output in html by passing in the parameter `--html=y` when you run pylint. You should then be able to put the output into a directory served by a web server and send out links to this easily enough. This won't format the issues in the same way that Jenkins does, but may suffice for your needs.

Here is the documentation on [pylint command line parameters](http://docs.pylint.org/run.html#command-line-options).